# C char array not working how I expected it to

Tags: c, char, arrays

The function below takes in a string of characters and a list of numbers. It then uses a loop to permute the characters based off of the numbers. The problems is that when I print the characters array using x and a while loop, it outputs the correct values "Moderation". When I print out the permutationvalues the same way, it correctly prints the right numbers "4560978123". But, whenever I print characters[0] it prints 'n' not 'M' as it should be. I am completely lost at why this is happening.

```
char* permute(const char* characters, const int permutationValues[]) {

  static char decryption[10];

  int x = 0;
  while(x < 10) {
    decryption[x] = characters[permutationValues[x]];
    printf("%c", characters[0]);

    x++;
  }

  return decryption;
}
```

I am fairly new to the C language so I hope its only a simple syntax mistake.

Here is my code in full.

```
#include <stdio.h>      // for I/O functions
#include <stdlib.h>     // generally useful
#include <stdbool.h>    // for the bool type
#include <stdint.h>     // for exact-width integer types
#include <inttypes.h>   // for exact-width integer output

//Permutation function declaration
char* permute(const char* characters, const int permutationValues[]);

int main() {

bool endOfFile = false; //Specifies if the end of the file was found
int encryption[10]; //This is the array that holds the encryption values
char text[10]; //The input text array that gets passed to be permuted
char* cText = text;
int x = 0; //The loop counter variable

FILE *cryptFile = fopen("TextIn.txt", "r"); //Open input file in "reading" mode
FILE *outputFile = fopen("TextOut.txt", "w"); //Open ouput file in "write" mode

//Reads in the first line of values into the program
fscanf(cryptFile, "%i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i", &encryption[0], &encryption[1], &encryption[2], &encryption[3],
&encryption[4], &encryption[5], &encryption[6], &encryption[7], &encryption[8], &encryption[9]);

//Writes the first line of data to the outputfile
fprintf(outputFile, "%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i\n", encryption[0], encryption[1], encryption[2], encryption[3], encryption[4], encryption[5], encryption[6], encryption[7], encryption[8], encryption[9]);

//Reads in and sets the permutation numbers from the second line into the array
fscanf(cryptFile, "%i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i", &encryption[0], &encryption[1], &encryption[2], &encryption[3],
&encryption[4], &encryption[5], &encryption[6], &encryption[7], &encryption[8], &encryption[9]);

//Writes the second line, the permutation values, to the outputfile
fprintf(outputFile, "%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i\n", encryption[0], encryption[1], encryption[2], encryption[3],
encryption[4], encryption[5], encryption[6], encryption[7], encryption[8], encryption[9]);

while(!endOfFile) {
//Pull in characters from file
int x = 0;
while(x < 10) {
  text[x] = fgetc(cryptFile);
  x++;
  if(text[x] == EOF) {
    endOfFile = true;
  }
}

//Permutes the 10 character text array using the given permutation
cText = permute(text, encryption); //Permutes the text until end of file

//Prints the permuted results
fprintf(outputFile, "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", cText[0], cText[1], cText[2], cText[3], cText[4], cText[5],
cText[6], cText[7], cText[8], cText[9]);
}

fclose(cryptFile); //Close the file

}


/*
* This function takes in a character array of values and a permutation sequence
* then will return a permuted array of characters.
* Pre:
*      Takes a pointer to a character array as the first argument that contains
*      the text that needs to be permutated. The second argument takes the 
*      permutation values as a pointer to a character array that will be used to 
*      permutate the given character array.
* Post: 
*      Returns a pointer to a character array that contains the permutated characters.
*      will return the same size array that was entered.
*/
char* permute(const char* characters, const int permutationValues[]) {

//DEREFERENCE LATER DO NOT FORGET
static char decryption[10];

int x = 0;
while(x < 10) {
decryption[x] = characters[permutationValues[x]];

printf("%c", characters[x]);

  x++;
}

return decryption;
}
```

**As a note I am running this using GCC in linux CentOS distro**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied your code exactly as you put it in [an example](http://ideone.com/LLuMnK). It does print the character 'M', ten times, even. Perhaps I'm not running the function correctly, or maybe you aren't.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* permute(const char* characters, const int permutationValues[]) {

  static char decryption[10];

  int x = 0;
  while(x < 10) {
    decryption[x] = characters[permutationValues[x]];
    printf("%c", characters[0]);

    x++;
  }

  return decryption;
}

int main(void) {

    int array[] = {4, 5, 6, 0, 9, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3};

    permute("Moderation", array);

    return 0;
}
```

Post the complete example if it's not working for you and we'll help you out.

**EDIT**

```
#include <stdio.h>      // for I/O functions
#include <stdlib.h>     // generally useful
#include <stdbool.h>    // for the bool type
#include <stdint.h>     // for exact-width integer types
#include <inttypes.h>   // for exact-width integer output

//Permutation function declaration
char* permute(const char* characters, const int permutationValues[]);

int main() {

bool endOfFile = false; //Specifies if the end of the file was found
int encryption[10]; //This is the array that holds the encryption values
char text[10]; //The input text array that gets passed to be permuted
char* cText = text;
int x = 0; //The loop counter variable

//Reads in the first line of values into the program
fscanf(stdin, "%i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i", &encryption[0], &encryption[1], &encryption[2], &encryption[3],
&encryption[4], &encryption[5], &encryption[6], &encryption[7], &encryption[8], &encryption[9]);

//Writes the first line of data to the outputfile
fprintf(stdout, "%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i\n", encryption[0], encryption[1], encryption[2], encryption[3], encryption[4], encryption[5], encryption[6], encryption[7], encryption[8], encryption[9]);

//Reads in and sets the permutation numbers from the second line into the array
fscanf(stdin, "%i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i %i", &encryption[0], &encryption[1], &encryption[2], &encryption[3],
&encryption[4], &encryption[5], &encryption[6], &encryption[7], &encryption[8], &encryption[9]);

//Writes the second line, the permutation values, to the outputfile
fprintf(stdout, "%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i%3i\n", encryption[0], encryption[1], encryption[2], encryption[3],
encryption[4], encryption[5], encryption[6], encryption[7], encryption[8], encryption[9]);

//while(!endOfFile) {
//Pull in characters from file

while(x < 10) {
  text[x] = fgetc(stdin);
  printf("captured: %c\n", text[x]);
  x++;
  if(text[x] == EOF) {
    endOfFile = true;
  }
}

//Permutes the 10 character text array using the given permutation
cText = permute(text, encryption); //Permutes the text until end of file

//Prints the permuted results
fprintf(stdout, "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", cText[0], cText[1], cText[2], cText[3], cText[4], cText[5],
cText[6], cText[7], cText[8], cText[9]);
//}

}


/*
* This function takes in a character array of values and a permutation sequence
* then will return a permuted array of characters.
* Pre:
*      Takes a pointer to a character array as the first argument that contains
*      the text that needs to be permutated. The second argument takes the 
*      permutation values as a pointer to a character array that will be used to 
*      permutate the given character array.
* Post: 
*      Returns a pointer to a character array that contains the permutated characters.
*      will return the same size array that was entered.
*/
char* permute(const char* characters, const int permutationValues[]) {

//DEREFERENCE LATER DO NOT FORGET
static char decryption[10];

int x = 0;
while(x < 10) {
decryption[x] = characters[permutationValues[x]];

printf("first: %c\n", characters[1]);

  x++;
}

return decryption;
}
```

This actually kinda works as you expected it would, check it out.

Comment: When I run my code with x instead of 0 "printf("%c", characters[x]);" I get "Moderation in temper, is always a virtue;". When I run with a 0 instead of x I get "nnnnnnnn". I'll post my code as an edit to my question above. The problem seems isolated to my function though.

Comment: It's impossible to test it without your input file. Could you provide us with the file contents, or better yet, make an example that doesn't read from a file, just to test your function?

Comment: Here is the exact input file I use. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ci56mqg20rerfjw/TextIn.txt

Comment: So, I updated the code in the link. I removed the outer loop so it only does one iteration, but as you can see by experimenting, your code still seems to work as expected. See the edit.

Comment: Just solved the problem. So the input file has a spare newline character floating around that pushes everything off by one value and screws up all of the output. The reason I didn't catch it earlier is that I thought I solved that problem a while ago, but lost the code at some point. Thanks for you time thought since you helped me prove that my algorithm wasn't wrong that that something else was the problem.